# linux: instant logout after correct ssh login

Tags: linux

I have a strange problem with my Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

After a correct Login via ssh, the connection gets closed immediatly.

Here's the output I get on the console after login with `ssh -vvv`:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-32-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
System information as of Mon Mar  4 10:29:54 CET 2013

System load:  0.18              Processes:           120
Usage of /:   2.9% of 77.23GB   Users logged in:     0
Memory usage: 54%               IP address for eth0: x.x.x.x
Swap usage:   9%

Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/

174 packages can be updated.
61 updates are security updates.

Last login: Mon Mar  4 10:29:28 2013 from y.y.y.y
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
#0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 0: close_fds r -1 w -1 e 6 c -1
Connection to x.x.x.x closed.
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 39 bytes in 0.7 seconds
debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 58.4
debug1: Exit status 1`
```

root is currently not allowed to connect directly via ssh, so I' ve only got one user for login.
Furthermore there's no X-Server, just console.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have read/write/execute access on your home directory? This is a common issue when access rights are wrong to the home directory. Exit status 1 means `Operation not permitted` which seems to support my theory :)

Comment: How to fix it? There's no other user to log in with to check permissions...

Comment: Well you can specify commands on the cmd-line to ssh. I'm not sure what solution would be best in your case, but perhaps use `sftp or scp` and try to fetch the sshd config, change so that root can login and after that upload it back and ssh as root temporarily and fix the issue.

Comment: How did it turn out? :)

Comment: In the end I installed a new server.... there was no chance getting any access. Still not knowing how to fix this error this case is closed;)